# React Native limit onScroll

Tags: listview, animation, react-native

Apologies for the beginner's React Native question....

I am putting together an animation on ListView scroll:

```
<ListView scrollEventThrottle={16}
    onScroll={
        Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: { y: this.state.animTranslateY}}}]
        )
    }
    ...
/>

<Animated.View style={[{height: 50, 
    position: 'absolute', 
    right: 0, 
    left: 0, 
    top: 0, 
    transform: [{ translateY: this.state.animTranslateY.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, this.state.infoHeight],
        outputRange: [this.state.infoHeight, 0] }) }]
    }]}
}>
    ...
</Animated.View>
```

I want to limit the animation so that, once the user has scrolled a certain distance (say, 100 pixels), the event no longer occurs, effectively fixing the animated view in place.

I've tried to insert a conditional in the onScroll event (`if (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < 100) {}`) but my syntax is off. I've tried creating a separate function but can't get this to work with `Animated.event` (and plain `event` produces a jolty effect, even with `scrollEventThrottle`).

Can anyone recommend how to properly inset the conditional? Or else produce a function using `Animated.event`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `ScrollView` instead. It has prop `scrollEnabled` which you can turn to false when you don't want user to be able to scroll any more. ScrollView also has `onScroll` so it should be easy to implement the logic here.

Here are the docs for ScrollView: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollenabled

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the design calls for the `ListView`/`ScrollView` to continue scrolling even after the `Animated.View` has reached its destination. In appearance, it's intended to be similar to a second `SectionHeader`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [extrapolate clamp](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.47/docs/animations.html#interpolation) to do this. From the docs: ‘By default, it will extrapolate the curve beyond the ranges given, but you can also have it clamp the output value.’ By clamping your output value you will stop your animation once it hits the last output value.

```
transform: [{ translateY: this.state.animTranslateY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, this.state.infoHeight],
    outputRange: [this.state.infoHeight, 0] }) }],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
}]}
```

This code will stop translating once your inputRange hits `this.state.infoHeight`.